# Draggable ruins image with invisibility

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanna add image with invisibility modified in Inkscape as a draggable object. I used container to scale it, but there is a white place size of container.

I just checked and image works great as position, but when I wrap with draggable - there is white place where invisibility should be. And when I scale it with container - whole container get white.
What can I do?

```
Positioned(
              top: top,
              left: left,
              child: Draggable(
                data: 10,
                onDragUpdate: (details) {
                  top = top + details.delta.dy;
                  left = left + details.delta.dx;
                  //print('${top}, ${left}');
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: Material(
                    child: Container(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 200,
                        child: Image.asset('match0.png'))),
                feedback: Material(
                    child: Container(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 200,
                        child: Image.asset('match0.png'))),
              )),
```

[image]

```
Positioned(
              top: top,
              left: left,
              child: Draggable(
                data: 10,
                onDragUpdate: (details) {
                  top = top + details.delta.dy;
                  left = left + details.delta.dx;
                  //print('${top}, ${left}');
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: Material(child: Image.asset('match0.png')),
                feedback: Container(
                    height: 200, width: 200, child: Image.asset('match0.png')),
              )),
```

[image]

```
Positioned(
              top: top,
              left: left,
              child: Container(
                  width: 200, height: 200, child: Image.asset('match0.png')))
```

[image]

Last view is my desire, but I need to be draggable. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION
I removed Material widget from inside of Draggable